# GLEW with OpenGL 1.1

Tags: opengl, glew

I am trying to run a solution on VS2012 from school, but I am getting

```
ERROR: Opengl 2.0 not supported
```

I've concluded that it's because they've started using GLEW for this assignment. Is there a way to get GLEW to work with my OpenGL 1.1?

Comment: It isn't a problem with GLEW. User code expects some GL 2.0 functions and, judging by GL version, determined that they are missing. GLEW just extracts function addresses - if function doesn't exist, it have no address, only re-implementing user code for older versions could help here (which is unreasonable - 1.1 is dead, even software implementations do much better now).

Comment: Are you doing something unusual like running in a VM or over Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest nVidia/AMD graphics driver

Also try:

```
  glewExperimental = true;
```